# Greying out textboxes

Tags: ms-access, checkbox, vba

Hey I have a checkbox that I want a textbox linked to that turns grey if the checkbox is not clicked. I have the code under the on click event on the checkbox and this works if the box is clicked the first time..... It allows the textbox to become enabled. But I want it to if the used accidently clicks the checkbox they can click off the checkbox and the textbox goes back grey again. Im not sure if I have the code on the wrong event for the checkbox or not. Thanks.

```
Private Sub FlightScheduleAffected_Click()
If IsNull(Me.FlightScheduleAffected.Value) Then
Me.TimeMOCCNotified.Enabled = False
Else
Me.TimeMOCCNotified.Enabled = True
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What language is this in? It looks like it may be Visual Basic, but that's just a guess...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of the checkbox should be true or false, it will never be null. You want your if statement to read

```
If Me.FlightScheduleAffected.Value Then
    Me.TimeMOCCNotified.Enabled = True
Else
    Me.TimeMOCCNotified.Enabled = False
End If
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I knew I was doing something dumb :)